# Smoke not visible after rendering

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation

I know this is not the first time this question is asked, but answers I have found do not fix my problem.

I'm trying to render some smoke, it's showing great on the simulation but invisible on render.

[Here was my .bend]

Comment: Could you please add some more information as to what you are doing exactly?  Maybe some screenshots of your nodes, domain settings, etc., or even [upload a .blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Comment: @PGmath I did, but the link expired and considering the answer it does not need to be reuploaded...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginner's mistake here.

I've hidden the domain on render because it was first showing like a solid.
That was not the right thing to do.

Comparing with QuickSmoke, I found that changing the density of domain's material from 1 to 0 made exactly what I wanted.